# We're sorry... invalidFederatedIdentityActionMessage from Keycloak after successfull login from ADFS over SAML,

Tags: keycloak, redhat, saml, adfs

I am getting success and responder status information too from ADFS, I checked for both of cases by turning on and off validate signature switch, setting `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true` and also to porto HTTP and https forwarding.

No one solution from above given worked well for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

•   You can try the settings in keycloak to be configured as below for it to act as a service provider to ADFS IdP so that you will be able to get the SAML requests to process correctly: -

```
 ‘ IdP URL: ${IDP_URL}/adfs/ls/

   NameID Policy Format: persistent

   WantAuthnRequestsSigned: true

   WantAssertionsSigned: true

   SignatureAlgorithm: RSA_SHA256

   SAMLSignatureKeyName: CERT_SUBJECT ‘
```

Thus, when you configure the above settings in keycloak, also ensure that you update NameID policy in keycloak as SP and similarly custom settings on the IdP side as well to ensure NameID is sent back as ‘persistent’ in format.

Comment: I added persistent in name id policy and values for name id is also mentioned same both the side in SP and IdP but still this doesn't work.

Comment: Was the name id policy format earlier 'unspecified' in ADFS, if no, then try doing this as I suspect, it has something to do with the outgoing name ID format or the outgoing claim type.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error message with a misconfigured identity provider on Keycloak 15.

Try this:

1. Go to https://[ADFS server hostname]/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml to download the ADFS server metadata
2. Find the X509Certificate fields marked 'signing' in the metadata
3. Go to your Keycloak Identity Provider definition -> settings -> 'Validating X509 Certificates' and insert the values from the metadata. Alternatively you can import the metadata file using Keycloak's import button when you create a new identity provider. Note: if the metadata contains multiple certificate values you can comma delimit them when you enter them in your keycloak identity provider definition.